# Anyone know why orderby would not be working?

Tags: channel-entries, orderby, sort

The orderby parameter seems to be giving some strange results on a site I'm building. It appears to be outputting 2, 3, 4 then 1. Any ideas why that would be?

Here's my code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="homepage_image_slider" orderby="slider_display_order" sort="asc"}
```

I've tried setting the field as text, number and integer and all give this strange result.

I'm running EE version 2.7.3

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you set any of the entries to be sticky?

Comment: That is a good question, but I'm afraid none of the four entries are set to be sticky.

Comment: Use integer for the field. Double check that the short name "slider_display_order" is correct, and that you aren't seeing a cached version of the results?

Comment: Field is set to integer, field name is correct, template caching is off for that template and I've cleared the EE caches. Starting to think it could be a bug rather than an error on my part?

Comment: Have you tried republishing all the entries? It could be possible that the entry with the one still has an ascii value instead of an integer. that would explain why it came after the 2,3,and 4. The ascii decimal value for "1" is 49, so if you publish and entry with 50, the output might look like 2,3,4,1(actually 49),50

Comment: Have you tried using alpha characters instead of numbers?